# Loop/recursion permutations of sublists of list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, recursion

I have a list of lists such as `[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3], ..., [0,1,2,3]]` whose length is not know a priori.

My goal is to loop through all combinations of permutations of the `[0,1,2,3]` sublists, each combination is a list of lists just like the original but where the order of some sublists have changed, eg. the second combination could be `[[0,1,3,2],[0,1,2,3], ..., [0,1,2,3]]` and the third   `[[0,3,1,2],[0,1,2,3], ..., [0,1,2,3]]`. I will use each of those for something else.

I imagine it like one constructs the binary table, first one would loop through the permutations of the first sublist, keeping the rest of the sublists unmodified; once they are done, they advance one permutation in the second sublist and go back to the first and loop through it again, and so on. A simpler example:

```
| [0,1] | [0,1] | [0,1] |
| [0,1] | [0,1] | [1,0] |
| [0,1] | [1,0] | [0,1] |
| [0,1] | [1,0] | [1,0] |
| [1,0] | [0,1] | [0,1] |
| [1,0] | [0,1] | [1,0] |
| [1,0] | [1,0] | [0,1] |
| [1,0] | [1,0] | [1,0] |
```

I'm having trouble with this because the way I'm thinking about it looks like I would need to have a variable number of nested loops. I don't know how to think about it in terms of recursion because once recursion I would need to loop as well, and once I `return` something that loop is lost.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would better to show example with lot smaller data like `[[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` with `itertools.permutations`:

```
import itertools as it
d = [[0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]]
r = list(it.product(*[it.permutations(i, len(i)) for i in d]))
```

Output:

```
[((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3)),  
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 2, 1, 3)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 2, 3, 1)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 3, 1, 2)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 3, 2, 1)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 0, 2, 3)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 0, 3, 2)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 0, 3)), 
 ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 0)),
 ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. I've never seen the asterisk used in that way, can you tell me what it does?

Comment: @miguelsxvi The `*` [unpacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) an iterator in either a signature or container.